# Some advice vs. advice vs. a piece of advice vs. any advice

Tags: uncountable-nouns, quantifiers

What are the differences, in terms of the amount of advice asked for, between the following questions:

1. Can you give me advice?
2. Can you give me some advice?
3. Can you give me a piece of advice?
4. Can you give me any advice?

From my understanding:

1 = 3: The asker is asking for only one single piece of advice.

2 = 4: The asker is asking for more than just one single piece of advice, but it's still ok to give just one single piece of advice.

Comment: Why would anyone ask specifically for only one piece of advice? In real life, the speaker would ask for any advice the other person can give them.

Comment: @KateBunting you are right. I understand the logics here. I am just trying to clarify the grammar.

Comment: A sentence may be grammatically correct but unidiomatic or even meaningless. "Can you give me a piece of cake?" is correct and natural, "Can you give me a piece of advice?" is correct but highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about #3: It does ask for a single piece of advice. The others simply ask for advice without indicating any specific amounts.

(Perhaps you can edit your question to indicate why you think that #1 asks for only one single piece of advice. I don't understand why you would think that.)

Comment: I think #1 asks for a single piece of advice simply because there are no quantifiers before the noun, but judging from your reply, probably I was mistaken. Also, how about 2=4?

Comment: @ASlowLearner The lack of quantifiers doesn't mean much. If I say "I want chocolate", I might want a single piece of chocolate or many pieces. As for #2 and #4, they are not the same as each other. (I assume that you mean "=" to indicate that they are the same.) The words "some" and "any" have their usual meanings, as given in dictionaries.